# What is the path separator I should use in cocos2d-x to be platform independent?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8.1, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am building for iOS, Android, and Windows Phone, and may support other platforms in future.

Currently I do this:

```
std::string filename = resourcePath + "/" + result + ".plist";
```

It seems to work for iOS (on the simulator), but I haven't checked for Android / WP yet.
What is the right way to add the path separator ? Is there an API or something that I can use to add the separator correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for the path separator in my code:

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WIN32)
#define PATH_SEPARATOR "\\"
#endif
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
#define PATH_SEPARATOR "/"
#endif
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
#define PATH_SEPARATOR "\/"
#endif

static const std::string Separator = PATH_SEPARATOR;

std::string nextBtnFileName = "images"+Separator+"speech"+Separator+"button_next.png";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What do you use for windows phone ? Also, in Android why do you use "\/" , instead of just "/" ? Is there any documentation you are referring to, or have you just tested this on all three platforms ?

Comment: @John no documentation to follow -this is what worked for me on the these three platforms. Have not deployed to windows phone so cant help with that.